# Struggling to inject Google ads into Rehub theme loop - any advice on plugins or custom code?

Tags: php, wordpress, ads

im trying to figure out how to Inject google ads into the rehub theme loop & gutenberg block on homepage. But every plugin or custom code added to the loop files i find wont work

if you look at https://ez007.net/freesamplesaustraliabymailonly/ homepage, youll see there is a custom gutenberg block for displaying the posts. Im trying to work out how to put a google feed ad every few posts. as this is a custom gutenberg block i still have to work out where to find the "loop" file for this

This seems very hard so i attempted to tackle the simpler job of injecting ads into a post loop. so ive been working on the search loop. and managed to get some code that seems to work in theory, but i get a console error on page https://ez007.net/freesamplesaustraliabymailonly/?s=makeup&post_type=post
the error is: No slot size for availableWidth=0

Below is the code i added to the search loop

```
    `<?php if (have_posts()) : 
     while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    
    // Your loop content, e.g., the_title(), the_excerpt(), etc.
    
    insert_adsense_ad('<script async     src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-4168476491259360"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- responsive -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-4168476491259360"
     data-ad-slot="6027972595"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
    <script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>', 4); ?>`
```